# Woocommerce orders datetime wrong

Tags: wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, utc

I fix datetime zone in functions.php of my child-theme to

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');
```

But It seems like the date of Woocommerce orders, even i go on an order to edit, the datetime displaying wrong.

How to fix all datetime of my website to `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok')` ?

Thank you

Comment: The timezone is editable through Wordpress General Settings > "Timezone"

Comment: Yes, i changed also here, but still have the same problem. Or must use this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_gmt_from_date ?

Comment: Usually editing timezone from backend fix the issue. can you check if your server timezone is the same timezone shown in woocommerce order ? in that case you might need to update the server timezone.

Comment: In General Settings, i have: Universal time is 2020-07-16 03:20:26. Local time is 2020-07-16 10:20:26. 
So local time is good, why other page it's incorrect..